# Kivy Camera with separated kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am building an app that will use a kivy camera to take pictures of text and runs it through OCR. My when I build by python and kivy file I cannot figure out how to separate them into different files in order to continue the app process.

I got this code from CodersHubb which works but I would like to break it out with Kivy language so I can add screens in the app.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 550)

class cameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global cam
        cam = Camera()

        btn = Button(text="Capture Total")
        btn.size_hint = (.1, .1)
        btn.font_size = 35
        btn.background_color = 'blue'
        btn.bind(on_press = self.capture_image)

        layout = GridLayout(rows=2, cols=1)
        layout.add_widget(cam)
        layout.add_widget(btn)

        return layout

    def capture_image(self, *args):
        global cam
        cam.export_to_png('image.png')

        print('Image captured and saved in current working directory')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cameraApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just want to write all the stuff in a *.kv file?
try this:
*.kv file:

```
GridLayout:
    rows:2
    cols:1
    Camera:
        id:camera
    Button:
        text:"Capture Total"
        size_hint: (.1,.1)
        font_size:35
        background_color:"blue"
        on_press:app.capture_image
```

main.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 550)

class cameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("MY_KV.kv")
        return self.root
    def capture_image(self, *args):
        cam = self.root.ids.camera
        cam.export_to_png('image.png')

        print('Image captured and saved in current working directory')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cameraApp().run()
```

don't forget to change filename in `build` function to your kv file

Comment: Yes I want to separate the camera into a kivy file, but I also want to use other screens within the app with the camera.

Comment: so read screenmanager docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html